# Best practice design pattern for defining "types" in a database with potential multi language requirement?

Tags: java, design-patterns, database-design, types

My question more specificity is this:

I want users on multiple front ends to see the "Type" of a database row. Let's say for ease that I have a person table and the types can be `Student`, `Teacher`, `Parent` etc.

The specific program would be java with hibernate, however I doubt that's important for the question, but let's say my data is modelled in to Entity beans and a Person "type" field is an enum that contains my 3 options, ideally I want my Person object to have a `getType()` method that my front end can use to display the type, and also I need a way for my front end to know the potential types.

With the enum method I have this functionality but what I don't have is the ability to easily add new types without re-compiling.

So next thought is that I put my types in to a config file and simply story them in the database as strings. my `getType()` method works, but now my front end has to load a config file to get the potential types AND now there's nothing to keep them in sync, I could remove a type from my config file and the type in the database would point to nothing. I don't like this either.

Final thought is that I create a PersonTypes database table, this table has a number for `type_id` and a `string` defining the type. This is OK, and if the foreign key is set up I can't delete types that I'm using, my front end will need to get sight of potential types, I guess the best way is to provide a service that will use the hibernate layer to do this.

The problem with this method is that my types are all in English in the database, and I want my application to support multiple languages (eventually) so I need some sort of properties file to store the labels for the types. so do I have a `PersonType` table the purely contains integers and then a properties file that describes the label per integer? That seems backwards?

Is there a common design pattern to achieve this kind of behaviour? Or can anyone suggest a good way to do this?

Regards,

Glen x

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the last approach that you have described. Having the type information in separate table should be good enought and it will let you use all the benefits of SQL for managing additional constraints (types will be probably Unique and foreign keys checks will assure you that you won't introduce any misbehaviour while you delete some records).

When each type will have `i18n` value defined in property files, then you are safe. If the type is removed - this value will not be used. If you want, you can change properties files as runtime.

The last approach I can think of would be to store `i18n` strings along with type information in `PersonType`. This is acceptable for small amount of languages, altough might be concidered an antipattern. But it would allow you having such method:

```
public String getName(PersonType type, Locale loc) {
  if (loc.equals(Locale.EN)) {
   return type.getEnglishName();
  } else if (loc.equals(Locale.DE)){
   return type.getGermanName();
  } else {
    return type.getDefaultName();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internationalizing dynamic values is always difficult. Your last method for storing the types is the right one.

If you want to be able to i18n them, you can use resource bundles as properties files in your app. This forces you to modify the properties files and redeploy and restart the app each time a new type is added. You can also fall back to the English string stored in database if the type is not found in the resource bundle.

Or you can implement a custom ResourceBundle class that fetches its keys and values from the database directly, and have an additional PersonTypeI18n table which contains the translations for all the locales you want to support.

Comment: I guess my first major issue is that I actually don't know what i18n is. Which I suppose is where i've been going wrong.

Comment: i18n means "Internationalization". It's a standard abbreviation chosen because the word has 18 chars between the starting I and the ending N.

Comment: So the idea is the the type table has a type_id and an i18n value which is an arbitrary value that is a pointer to a definition in a properties file?

Comment: I would do it the other way: if the type table contains the IDs "foo" and "bar", I would have a properties file containing something like "foo=..." and "bar="...". The properties file uses the IDs in the database.

Comment: Which would make my type table have a single column?

Comment: Yes, just as your enum doesn't have any specific field. You could imagine adding a purely informative description column, which could help the translators.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following practices:

1. Use **singleton design pattern**
2. Use cashing framework such as **EhCashe** for cashe type of person and reload when need.